# From where are the list values fetched in this excel file?

Tags: excel

I've spent way too much time on this now so I have to ask. Where are the drop down list values stored for the `Role` and `PRO Affiliation` columns? I know how to make dropdown lists, but only when fetched from a different column. In this case I can't find where those lists are.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[The Excel File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/peexy0hkq0px8kk/Excel.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Please share printscreens of your file, we dont like to open external files not knowing what is in them.

Comment: Due to security concerns, I don't follow links which lead to macro-laden files. Please ask a self-contained question.

Comment: Understandable. Main post updated with screenshots. So the values in the dropdown list is a mystery where they come from.

Comment: There is a named range - go to Insert : name : define and see the detail in the list.

Comment: It's in the Role column of the Role table. You can type `Role` in the address bar (left to the formula bar) to get to it

Comment: @Slai I've tried that. It doesn't take me anywhere. It's gone. Updated with new pictures...

Comment: Seems like they might be in a hidden or very hidden sheet. To unhide hidden sheets right click any sheet tab and click Unhide, but I am not fully sure how very hidden sheets can be unhidden on Mac .. maybe this can help https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/810049-very-hidden-sheet-in-excel-for-mac.html#post2684962

Comment: @Slai Thanks, I'll check it out. I found the values in a file called `xl/sharedStrings.xml` when deconstructing the excel file. Any idea where those are reached from within Excel?

Comment: no, xl/sharedStrings.xml contains all string values from cells for the whole file

Comment: You can't unhide the worksheet as the workbook structure is protected, and a password is required to unhide a worksheet.  But there are a bunch of Tables on that worksheet, including the two mentioned above.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  Ah ok. So the only way is to unlock the workbook?

Comment: If you want to be able to alter those tables, you'll need the password (or some method of bypassing it).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks Ron. I’ll see if I find a way. That explains a lot.

Comment: @Slai vba on a mac will very hidden & very unhidden

Comment: @Slai Screenshot with the vbe added. In an unprotected workbook, would that window contain anything?

Comment: BINGO! Found a way to remove the protection and could finally unhide that sheet. Screenshot posted! Mystery solved! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score -2):

In the cell of interest, go to the "DATA" tab and choose the "DATA VALIDATION". 
The options opening up will show you where your data is coming from:[image]